# Objective-C Soap Proxy Generator similar to whats in .NET

Tags: .net, objective-c, web-services, soap, proxy

We have a contractor doing an Iphone native app in objective-c.  They need to call some of our web services to get data.  Is there some kind of proxy generator for obj-c that will create native objects that call web services?  C#/.NET has this built in--you just add a service reference in visual studio or you use a command line tool and the web services appear as local, native objects as does the data they return.  I want to avoid having him parse the soap xml himself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this any help?

http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/